# how to use UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle and UITableViewCellStyleValue1 in the same cell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, cell

I want the Cell to have a Subtitle and also a Value1

is it possible to use

```
UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
```

and

```
UITableViewCellStyleValue1
```

in the same cell?

I tried that, using this:

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"123";
```

But it can only work on one of them.

Comment: You can't. You will have to make a subclass of `UITableViewCell` and add the labels yourself.

Comment: how to do that? can you help?

Comment: First Google hit: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-crafting-custom-uitableview-cells--mobile-15702

Answer (score 2):

You can't have two cell styles at the same time, but the simplest way to achieve what you're looking for is to define a custom cell and make two labels.

I usually make outlets called `primaryLabel` and `secondaryLabel` so that I don't clash with the system labels. Then, I wire them up to a custom cell. (You can do this either in a nib or a storyboard.)

The default cell styles will only get you so far.